# Loading Issue Using Filter Function in Documentation Review Queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, review-queues

While testing the filter functionality in the Documentation Review Queue, I came across a bug that causes the loading indicator to spin forever and the page would refuse to refresh.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on "Review"
2. Using the "filter" functionality, enter **more than** 3 filters; click "OK" subsequently.

The page would begin to dim and the loading indicator would start to spin; and it would stay so forever.

[image]

Comment: **Read the warning**! You’re only supposed to use 3. You’re lucky you computer didn’t spontaneously combust ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error handler had an error... it wasn't implemented :(

A fix is being pushed out now.

Thanks!